# How can I use embedded ruby to make very simple dynamic websites (like with PHP)?

Tags: ruby

So for simple, mostly static sites, I feel that I do not need a full ruby framework like Rails or Sinatra.

I'd just like to dry up my html with some backend code.

Normally, I'd just use php, which makes this sort of thing very simple. However there are some gems I'd like to use in the project without a php alternative.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: At a minimum use Sinatra if you're going to use any Ruby code. It makes the job a *lot* easier than trying to roll your own using CGI. Haml, or Erubis, with Sinatra will cover the same bases PHP would. That said, your question solicits opinions, not facts, which makes it have a high likelihood of being closed.

Comment: I'm not asking for opinions at all. It's a technical question- how can ruby be used like php in the least bulky and least opinionated (MVC) way possible.

Comment: @johncorser If you just want to parse some html templates with Ruby, you can use ERB, Haml, or Slim. But if you're creating a dynamic website, you'll eventually need some way to receive requests, gather data from a database, and generate an appropriate response based on the URI and parameters. If that's your ultimate goal, just use Sinatra. There's no point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I'd love to use ERB. The problem is I can't get passed the CGI without some sort of additional gem or framework to run on the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERB is not executed directly like PHP. A framework of some kind (that supports erb) is necessary in order to use it.